# Print Specified Pages of a Report

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a report that has multiple subreports with page breaks in between each. I want to print only specified pages according to what is entered into one of the text controls (automatically filled in based on the selection from a combo box) on the main form. For example, when the `ClientName` control says `123,` I want only pages `1` and `4` of the report to print.

I have tried using `DoCmd.PrintOut acPages`, but this was not the solution I was looking for as it print out pages `1-4` and not just `1` and `4`.

I'm thinking that `acPrintRange` might be something else to try, but I am pretty new to Access and I'm not quite sure how to use this piece of code. I think that in order to use it the way I want I am going to have to use it in combination with `If...Then...Else`.

An example of how this would be done or a template of what the code would look like would be greatly appreciated!

To be clear, I am trying to code this into the `OnClick` event of a command button for several different page pairings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non-contiguous ranges, you'll have to call `DoCmd.PrintOut` multiple times, once per range.

E.g. to print pages 1 and 4-5:

```
DoCmd.PrintOut PrintRange:=acPages, PageFrom:=1, PageTo:=1
DoCmd.PrintOut PrintRange:=acPages, PageFrom:=4, PageTo:=5
```

Note: using names parameters like above helps to make your code self-explanatory.